# Hiding ChromeDriver.exe in C# and how to embed it with executable

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Every time I execute application. ChromeDriver.exe gets execute. I simply wanna hide it while application gets executed. It should run in silent or headless mode.
I have my code written in C# with selenium.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the `ChromeDriver` instance, you can add this:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddOption("--headless");

driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

This will tell ChromeDriver to run without rendernig a browser.